# PHP 8 strict type is forced on native function?

Tags: php, types, casting, type-conversion, php-8

My code works on PHP 7:

```
round(microtime(),3);
```

but in PHP 8:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: round(): Argument #1 ($num) must be
> of type int|float, string given in [...][...]:4 Stack trace: #0
> [...]...: round('0.21066100 1646...', 3) #1 {main} thrown in
> [...][...] on line 4

If I force cast:

```
round((float)microtime(),3);
```

It works but all the force of PHP is autocast and non strict type! How can I use PHP 8 if all native functions in all my billions of lines codes must be edited to force cast everywhere?

Is there a way to preserve automatic type conversion on internal functions?

I take microtime() like an example in my code but:

```
round("200 42");
```

As the same problem, so the solution is not just `microtime(true)`, it's not the topic here.

The problem is, if in my code I use a native function, there are potential bugs and I can't know it (error occur only when the script is running), so if I let PHP 8, may be, certain pages of my site don't work and I have no possibility to know it! It's A BIG Problem!

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.other-changes.php

> The math functions abs(), ceil(), floor() and round() now properly
> heed the strict_types directive. Previously, they coerced the first
> argument even in strict type mode.

So this function must be focused to update code and not all native functions!

Comment: `microtime()` returns something like `"0.00369800 1644622698"`. You most likely want `microtime(true)`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no, it's just an exemple: round("200") as the same problem, and I dont want edit all my code. I edit the post ;)

Comment: `round("200");` will work, since string `"200"` can be coerced to int/float type. However something like `"200 42"` is ambiguous. And you really do want to update your code at places where ambiguous typecasting used to be valid... because it gives rise to all sorts of anomalies that will, in time, take longer to chase down than it'd take for you to update your code.

Comment: "all the force of PHP is autocast and non strict type" - Math functions like `round()` only require strict types if you enable strict types (`declare(strict_types=1);`. That was [changed in PHP/8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.other-changes.php#migration80.other-changes.functions.standard).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no, without strict_type, there is the error ! test yourself ;)

Comment: Just saw your edit regarding `round("200 42");`. In that case you're rounding something that isn't a number, not just as type, but in a logical meaning. PHP has been hardening some previous behaviours that didn't make much sense. I don't think there's much you can do about that in general terms.

Comment: @MarkusAO I have some other errors about other native function, so there is many type error and I cant know where without test/run EVRY files PHP ... it's not a good thing

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it's works in PHP7 and it's works with force cast, why autocast was inactive in PHP8? it's stupid...

Comment: I've illustrated in my answer why it's a _very good thing_ that ambiguous typecasting doesn't happen with math functions... What other native functions are you getting TypeErrors with?

Comment: Review the [migrating from PHP 7.4 to 8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php), look for the changes in your code, and refactor where needed. Updating a major version of any library will typically cause a lot of BC-breaks across your entire codebase. PHP 8 and above is moving toward strict-type intentions to prevent ambiguous return values that lead to unexpected results. For example [`0 == 'foo'` is `true`](https://3v4l.org/EHmr4) in PHP <= 7.4

Comment: @WillB. truth table PHP are borring and idiot from always ^^ 0 == false and 1 == true is stupid, but it's not the problem here and there is nowhere write in migration guide, this problem of non-autocast for round() (or other native function)

Comment: @Matrix Now and then, PHP devs fix some language behaviours that didn't make any sense in the first place. It didn't make sense that you could `count()` a `DateTime` object and get `1` or that `'abc' == 0` was `true`. Your code relied in some of those dubious behaviours, which is unfortunate, but it isn't fair to say that PHP devs were wrong when fixing it. You wouldn't have ended up with such code if the language hadn't misbehaved initially.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes but its shocking there is no alert in guide migration to possible new bug insert in my code without i know it... EDIT : ok it's not in "break change" but in "other change" : https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.other-changes.php

Comment: The `round('200 42')` case is probably covered by this text in the [incompatible changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) section: "Numeric string handling has been altered to be more intuitive and less error-prone". I agree that it isn't a big warning.

Comment: @Matrix the truth table break is just one of the more common examples people encounter of the many obscure BC-breaks from PHP 7.4 to 8 and is at the core for the reasoning of the `strict_types=1` [changes to `round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.other-changes.php) and others. The changes in 8 are a means to force the use of best-practices in PHP. While other ambiguous behaviors, such as [mixed return types of internal functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/consistent_type_errors#issues), are expected to be deprecated in later versions of PHP 8 becoming breaks in PHP 9.

Comment: @WillB. the force of PHP is non-strict type, I hope they will let the option ;)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to force cast to match native function signatures everywhere, unless `strict_types` is declared. You do need to ensure that the variables you feed into those functions can be *unambiguously typecast* into the expected datatype. We have a case in point with the math functions, where you really want to have a *valid number* as an argument, regardless of datatypes:

```
php > echo round("200");
200

php > echo round("200 12");
Warning: Uncaught TypeError: round(): 
Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given
```

Here the string `"200"` works, because it's an unambiguous number. However, `"200 12"` will not, since it's ambiguous. Suppose you cast it:

```
php > echo (int) "200 12";
200
```

Your `"200 12"` becomes `(int) 200`. Is that what you expected? Again:

```
php > echo (float) "gummy bears";
0

php > echo 200 + "1";
201

php > echo 200 - "gummy bears" + "1";
Warning: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: int - string
```

These are the sorts of anomalous evaluations that would pass in earlier versions of PHP, and it's a blessing we now get a `TypeError` instead. Variables should only ever be typecast *losslessly*, "reckless" typecasting and corrupted data has been the source of countless evasive bugs.

Also see: [PHP Manual on Numeric Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php) ... specifically the sections on what can be *interpreted as a number* and what can't. Basically, if your variable passes [`is_numeric()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), it's fine for math operations -- and if not, you deserve an error message! Here's the list of samples from the manual:

```
$foo = 1 + "10.5";                // $foo is float (11.5)
$foo = 1 + "-1.3e3";              // $foo is float (-1299)
$foo = 1 + "bob-1.3e3";           // TypeError as of PHP 8.0.0, $foo is integer (1) previously
$foo = 1 + "bob3";                // TypeError as of PHP 8.0.0, $foo is integer (1) previously
$foo = 1 + "10 Small Pigs";       // $foo is integer (11) and an E_WARNING is raised in PHP 8.0.0, E_NOTICE previously
$foo = 4 + "10.2 Little Piggies"; // $foo is float (14.2) and an E_WARNING is raised in PHP 8.0.0, E_NOTICE previously
$foo = "10.0 pigs " + 1;          // $foo is float (11) and an E_WARNING is raised in PHP 8.0.0, E_NOTICE previously
$foo = "10.0 pigs " + 1.0;        // $foo is float (11) and an E_WARNING is raised in PHP 8.0.0, E_NOTICE previously
```

In conclusion, you really do want to update your code at places where ambiguous typecasting used to be valid... In the long run, you'll spend less time updating your code than you would in chasing down anomalies resulting from variable values that were corrupted when "autocasting".

Comment: You imagine if each call of each native function is a possible futur bug? I will not retest all my code, the problem is not specific to "round()" but PHP8, because autocast was remove...

Comment: ok the autocast was remove only for round() floor() ceil() and abs(), so it's possible to know where there is bug : https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.other-changes.php

Comment: @Matrix typecasting / type juggling has not been removed in PHP 8. As you can see above, `round("200")` works fine. You only get type errors when you try to use *non-numeric strings* for math operations, and you really do want to have errors shown if with _invalid arguments_ that would lead to nonsensical evaluation.

Comment: @Matrix That text means that those functions now work as expected under `strict_types=1`, which I think you aren't using. What PHP no longer does is to happily produce type castings that are illogical or counter-intuitive, such as `(int)'gummy bears'`.

Comment: @Matrix one common solution to prevent future issues is to implement [Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4840059/1144627) that covers the entirety of your codebase and test it against various versions of PHP. Allowing you to automate the testing of your code and catch errors and unexpected behavior before migrating your environment(s) to a newer version of PHP. For example when upgrading to [7.2.19 causing `DatePeriod`](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.19) to throw an exception that it did not in PHP 7.2.18.

Comment: @WillB. nomody test native function ^^

Comment: @Matrix Your codebase utilizes the native function(s), of which your unit tests would be calling, thereby catching the resulting exception of the native function usage when executed on PHP 8, pointing you to the unexpected behavior of the native function(s) as well as your own.

Comment: For your unit testing illustration, where native operations may fail and need to be checked for: `function get_me_gummybears($amount) { return $amount - 1; // because aliens take one }`. Then the test iterations with different inputs: `$nums = ['1', 3, 5.5, 'lots of', '-1.3e3', true]; foreach($nums as $num) { get_me_gummybears($num); }`. @Todo: Ensure gummmybear request is a valid number. Otherwise throw `GummyBearLogicException` or maybe display request form again.

Comment: Think OP knows what strict_types does. We are facing the same issue after php8 upgrade its behaving as if strict_types is enabled across the entire application when previously it only affected files with the strict_type declaration. Im looking for an swer to this too.

Answer (score 2):

same problem with in_array:

```
$a = null;
in_array( 1, $a ); // works in php 7 -null becomes [], fails in php 8
in_array( 1, (array)$a ); // works in php 8 but we don't want to type this... autocast is what made PHP attractive in the first place.
```

Comment: I don't already test, but mybe override native function for force cast... I found this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230883/how-to-override-built-in-php-functions

Comment: This is again a scenario where you really _want an error_. It's not a problem in how this is implemented, it's a problem with your code if you do an array lookup but don't ensure that you're dealing with an array. Use `if(is_array($a)) { ... }` to conditionally evaluate, and sensibly handle situations where your variable for some reason isn't an array. If something isn't an array, but your code expects an array, it means you have an exception prior to that code that you should be taking care of.

Comment: If you reasonably expect _array or null_ as the only two options, you can for example use `in_array(1, $a ?? [])` the null-coalescing operator to provide a default empty array in place of an `if/else` construct. I do that in some specific cases with `foreach($a ?? [] as $val)` where, if the variable is null instead of an array, the loop simply doesn't iterate -- instead of wrapping the loop in a `if(!is_null($a)) { ... }` conditional.