# Issue with PHP8 and Holiday Script

Tags: php, php-8

I have upgraded my test server to PHP 8 and I am having an issue with my yearly staff holiday script (works out how many hours / minutes have been taken and how many left) and firstly gave me the below error message;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: int - string in
```

After a bit of Google and SO, I think that this has been solved by adding (int) to the - string.

I am now getting the below error message;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string / int in on line 169
```

See line 169's code below.

Anything that I have tried from SO and Google does not appear to be working.

Line 169

```
$hours      =   floor($minutes/60).'.'. ($minutes % 60);
```

Original Code

```
<?php
    
    $time                       =   $holiday_remain_time['total_year_holiday_hours_complete'];
    $total_year_holiday_hours   =   $holiday_remain_time['total_year_holiday_hours'] * 60;
    $remaining                  =   ($total_year_holiday_hours - $holiday_remain_time['total_year_holiday_hours_complete']);

    $minutes    =   $holiday_remain_time['total_year_holiday_hours_complete'];
    $hours      =   floor($minutes/60).'.'. ($minutes % 60);
    $showHours  =   floor($minutes/60).' Hour '. ($minutes % 60) . ' Minute';

    $reminutes    =   $remaining;
    $reshowHours  =   floor($reminutes/60).' Hour '. ($reminutes % 60) . ' Minute';

?>
```

Modified Code

```
<?php
    
    $time                       =   $holiday_remain_time['total_year_holiday_hours_complete'];
    $total_year_holiday_hours   =   $holiday_remain_time['total_year_holiday_hours'] * 60;
    $remaining                  =   ((int)$total_year_holiday_hours - (int)$holiday_remain_time['total_year_holiday_hours_complete']);

    $minutes    =   $holiday_remain_time['total_year_holiday_hours_complete'];
    $hours      =   floor($minutes/60).'.'. ($minutes % 60);
    $showHours  =   floor($minutes/60).' Hour '. ($minutes % 60) . ' Minute';

    $reminutes    =   $remaining;
    $reshowHours  =   floor($reminutes/60).' Hour '. ($reminutes % 60) . ' Minute';

?>
```

Database

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_year_holiday_hours` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_year_holiday_hours_complete` int(100) DEFAULT NULL
```

Output Example

```
Yearly Holiday : 40 Hours
Already Holiday Taken : 15 Hours
Remaining Holiday Hour: 25 Hours
```

Display code

```
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($holiday_activity as $record){ 

                    $hour       =   $record['hour'] * 60;
                    $minutes    =   $hour + $record['minute'];
                    $hours      =   intdiv($minutes, 60).' Hour '. ($minutes % 60) . ' Minute';

                ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php $date = $record['date']; $bits = explode('-', $date); $date = $bits[2] . '/' . $bits[1] . '/' . $bits[0]; echo $date; ?></td>
                <td><?php $date = $record['end_date']; $bits = explode('-', $date); $date = $bits[2] . '/' . $bits[1] . '/' . $bits[0]; echo $date; ?></td>
                <td><?= $hours; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $record['status']; ?></td>

                <td>
                <?php if($record['status'] == 'active'){ echo 'cannot change'; } else{ ?>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop<?php echo $record['id']; ?>">
                    Edit
                    </a> <!-- <a href="delete.php" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</a> -->
                <?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I have changed the database columns to INT and ran var_dump($hours); which shows NULL before the Modified Code above.

If I run var_dump($hours); after the Modified Code, it shows nothing.

Comment: The error messages usually have a line number with them of where the error occurrs. Could you include information on which line of code it fails?

Comment: Seems like the problem is now in `$minutes/60`, but we don't know what `$minutes` contains. PHP 8 has no problem [dividing a number in string by an integer](https://3v4l.org/WJTfn), even if followed by text, so I guess there's not actually a number in there. It could also be that `$reminutes/60` is the problem, but we don't where the error occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 8 strict type is forced on native function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71296583/php-8-strict-type-is-forced-on-native-function)

Comment: I've added the line number of code and code that is reporting the error message. $minutes contains a number. This was working fine and still is working fine on PHP7 (Live System).

Comment: Look *very carefully* at what is in `$minutes`. As others have said, this message *only occurs* if the value is not made up of digits. `$minutes` is coming from a `VarChar` column `total_year_holiday_hours_complete`, so probably somebody has put something unexpected into that column, like `'N/A'` or `'up to 5'`. In PHP 7, this would have been logging a Warning, so check your live logs, and you will probably see lots of messages saying "A non-numeric value encountered".

Comment: Actually, in the php file, it is line 169 - I've only copied the sections out that are most appropriate.

Comment: Hi IMSoP, I have changed the fields from Varchar to int(100) already.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($minutes);` right before the line it fails on and post that output.

Comment: var_dump($holiday_remain_time); - array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["total_year_holiday_hours"]=> string(2) "40" ["total_year_holiday_hours_complete"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: var_dump($minutes); - just before it fails - string(0) ""

Comment: The DB value of total_year_holiday_hours_complete is 12

Comment: "The DB value of total_year_holiday_hours_complete is 12" - clearly it's not, as your own debug statement shows. Either that, or `$holiday_remain_time` isn't coming directly from the database, but you haven't shown any of that code.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of prompting, you have confirmed that `$minutes`, which is coming from the database, is indeed *not a number*, it is an empty string.

So the simplest reproduction of the error is this:

```
$minutes = "";
echo $minutes / 60;
```

[As you can see on this handy site](https://3v4l.org/Lv51P) that will have been logging a Warning on your existing PHP 7 server, which has now become an Error.

It is up to you to decide what you want to do with that empty string (and any other invalid input). You could output an error telling the user to fix it, or you could treat it as zero. Perhaps an empty string should be zero, but other unexpected inputs should be rejected:

```
if ( $minutes === '' ) {
    $minutes = 0;
}
elseif ( ! ctype_digit($minutes) ) {
   // You probably want something more useful than a die()
   // Maybe throw an exception, or log something somewhere and skip the item
   die("total_year_holiday_hours_complete contains non-digit characters!");
}
```

Comment: Added (int) before floor on line 169 - started working fine. String can be 0 as hours used can be 0.

Comment: @Pongle Just to be clear, "0" is a different string from "". That's why I say that "" is an "invalid input" - if it's explicitly zero, "0" would be the logical way to store that in a string / VarChar. Note also that `(int)` will convert _all_ invalid inputs to 0, so `"defintely not zero"` would also be silently treated as zero, which is why I suggested a more explicit check.

Comment: An upvote for persistence!